# How to make a rounded corner SurfaceView in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app to stream video. For this I am using SurfaceView. Is there any way to make the SurfaceView rounded corner?

I tried the following code to make the rounded corner. It can make Button, Layout, TextView rounded corner but it is not working on SurfaceView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >


<!-- view background color -->


<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="#FF0000" >
</stroke>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners 
    android:radius="20dp">
</corners>
```

This code shows a red rounded border over the SurfceView but the view is not rounded itself.

How can I make the SurfaceView rounded corner?

Please help me in this issue.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you must process each one of the frames of the video to mask them.

Check the use of lockCanvas. Basically you must create a secondary thread that is all the time locking the canvas, taking the video frame, masking it, drawing it and releasing the canvas.

Check this article for an example:

http://androidtutorialsandtips.blogspot.com/2012/01/overriding-ondraw-method-in-surfaceview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can imlement it with opengl es. There is an article(https://medium.com/@fabrantes/rounded-video-corners-on-android-3467841cc1b) explaining how to do it and it provided source code in github.  But the author use GLSurfaceView.
If you want to do it with SurfaceView . You should init opengl es context by yourself, you can refer to Grafika(https://github.com/google/grafika) to init opengl es. Grafika us egl14 which is available since android 4.2. You can use egl10 instead.